# How to meaningfully use additional properties of an assosiation prox object?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Consider a many-to-many relationship of Things where the order of the children (or parents) matters. So the association object ("Link") has an additional property "position". When I fill the structure, I obviously can't use the "association-jumping" append() method because I need to explicitly access the Link object to set the "position" attribute. Sad but understandable.

What I'm struggling with now is to retrieve the children of a Thing in the order given by the Link's position property. Is that in any way possible? If not, the association_proxy is not of any use to me in either populating nor retrieving the data which makes me wonder what it is good for at all. I've tried to wrap my head around the use cases in the [documentation](https://docs-sqlalchemy.readthedocs.io/ko/latest/orm/extensions/associationproxy.html#sqlalchemy.ext.associationproxy.association_proxy) but they don't seem to apply for my situation.

Here's a self-contained example:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, CHAR, Column, Integer,\
    String, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.ext.associationproxy import association_proxy
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

class Thing(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'thing'
    id            = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name          = Column(String(255))
    up = association_proxy('coll_up', 'up')
    down = association_proxy('coll_down', 'down')

class Link(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'link'
    id_up         = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('thing.id'),
                           primary_key=True)
    id_down       = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('thing.id'),
                          primary_key=True)
    position      = Column(Integer)
    up = relationship('Thing', primaryjoin=id_up == Thing.id,
                       backref='coll_down')
    down = relationship('Thing', primaryjoin=id_down == Thing.id,
                        backref='coll_up')

if __name__ == '__main__':
# I know that for convenient append()ing stuff I'd need an __init__()
# method, but see comments below

    engine = create_engine('sqlite://')
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
    Session = sessionmaker(engine)

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        db = Session()
        root = Thing(name='Root thing')
        db.add(root)
# inserting "reversed" to have something to sort
        for i in reversed(range(5)):
            t = Thing(name='Thing %d' % i)
# If Link had an __init__ method I could use root.append(t), but...
            db.add(t)
# ...in order to set position, I need to explicitly use the association
# object anyway
            l = Link(up=root, down=t, position=i)
            db.add(l)
        db.commit()

# OK, so far the association_proxy construct hasn't been of any use. Let's
# see about retrieving the data...

        root = db.query(Thing).filter_by(name='Root thing').one()
        for thing in root.down:
            print(thing.name)
# This, as expected. prints the elements in the order in which they were
# inserted (which is "reversed"). How can I sort them by the "position"
# property of the "Link" element, or is the associaton object useless in
# this scenario?
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest investigating the [`order_by`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/relationship_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.relationship.params.order_by) parameter of relationships. You can can order the ORM's organization of related object by the child's properties. *(Ordering **will not** work without `session.commit()`)*.

**Assuming you want to order by `Link.position`:**

```py
class Link(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'link'
    id_up = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('thing.id'), primary_key=True)
    id_down = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('thing.id'), primary_key=True)
    position = Column(Integer)

    # Note the syntax for order_by -- the ORM model is referred to as a string
    up = relationship(
        'Thing', primaryjoin=id_up == Thing.id,
        order_by='Link.position',
        backref='coll_down'
        )

    down = relationship(
        'Thing',
        primaryjoin=id_down == Thing.id,
        order_by='Link.position',
        backref='coll_up'
        )
```

If you need more rigid ordering, meaning, ordering before the child is committed to the session, you can define an [`orderinglist`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/extensions/orderinglist.html#module-sqlalchemy.ext.orderinglist) on the relationship which "intercept" and reorganize relationships in the ORM. *(Ordering **will** work without  `session.commit()`)*.

```py
from sqlalchemy.ext.orderinglist import ordering_list

class Link(Base):
    ...
    
    up = relationship(
        'Thing',
        primaryjoin=id_up == Thing.id,
        order_by='Link.position',
        collection_class=ordering_list('position')
        backref='coll_down'
        )
    ...
```

As a next step, if you're looking to organize your position based on ids (perhaps `position = id_up - id_down`), I'd suggest looking into [sqlalchemy's event API](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/events.html#sqlalchemy.orm.MapperEvents.before_update). An elegant approach would be trigger recalculation of relevant attributes based on a relevant update. *(Ex: `id_up` is increased by 1, increase position by 1).*

Comment: Thanks for the good answer -- the overlooked order_by parameter in the relationship as well as pointers to further refinements. I find the SQLALchemy documentation excellent but I sometimes do get lost in its complexity.

Comment: Sorry -- I answered before I tested your solution, and it doesn't work. No ordering takes place. Doesn't have to do with commit() -- I always had that in there.

Comment: I'm sorry that you're struggling with this. Perhaps you can elaborate further on what you're trying to do? @musbur --> perhaps amend the Q?